# Deselect Multiple Edges

Tags: modeling

I want to deselect multiple edges on my model. I currently know how to deselect one edge at a time by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd>, but I am looking for a faster way for that. Deselecting one by one takes forever.

I am using the **3dsmax preset**, so the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd> is deselecting edges one by one.

For example, you could use the selection tools in 3dsmax (lasso, circle, box, spray etc.) to quickly deselect verts / edges / faces by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>(Click+Draw a region)</kbd>.

Comment: Do you mean  shift+click? Ctrl+Click is for lasso select.

Comment: I am using the 3dsmax preset from the splash screen. Shift+Click doesn't do anything.

Comment: Cant get to enable the circle/lasso select tools as I am using the 3dsmax preset.

Comment: It seems that *Lasso select* is not assigned in the max preset, but circle select (C) and box select (B) should both work. You can also assign the lasso select tool to a shortcut if you want.

Comment: I bit the bullet and am using the Default Blender shortcuts from the splash screen. I did get to access the circle (C), and could deselect the elements using Shift+LMB. Thanks...!